# авторизация яндекс деньги

Tags: python, flask, yandex-money

Пытаюсь авторизировать приложение и получить код. Использую flask и python версии 3.5

```
ym_account='***@yandex.ru'
client_id='***'
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ymon():
    scope = ['account-info payment.to-account("%s").limit(,%s)' % (ym_account, 10)]

    auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_id, redirect_uri, scope) + '&response_type=code'

    token = Wallet.get_access_token(client_id=client_id,code=flask.request.args['code'],redirect_uri=auth_url)['access_token']


    return token
```

вот что я получаю в ответ

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

в чем может быть причина ?

Comment: Что такое `Wallet`?

Comment: @andreymal  python обертку использую , объект wallet для авторизации отсюда  https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-python                        from yandex_money.api import Wallet, ExternalPayment

Comment: @egorkh не решили проблему?